# laravel how to secure passing data from blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel

How can I secure data from being change if user used inspect element in chrome to change id, price..etc, I know I can't prevent users from using inspect element and do changes but I dont want these changes to have effect
I used this in blade to pass data from button using ajax

```
<button id="Item_root" data-id="{{$product->product_id}}"  data-detailsfield="{{$product->product_details}}" data-titlefield="{{$product->product_title}}" data-pricefield="{{$product->product_price}}" data-photofield="{{ asset('images/' . $product->product_image) }}" class="Item_root Button_root">
```

**and from inspect element user can see it like this:**

```
    <button id="Item_root" data-id="19" data-detailsfield="Serves 6-8 People" data-titlefield="Package # 8U" data-pricefield="105.99" data-photofield="http://localhost/crisp/public/images/Chicken-Fajitas.jpg" class="Item_root Button_root">
   <div class="Item_image" style="background-image:url('http://localhost/crisp/public/images/Chicken-Fajitas.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="Item_itemContent">
      <div class="Item_topSection">
         <span class="Item_name styles_just-right styles_base styles_spacing-base">Package # 8U</span>
         <span class="Item_price styles_just-right styles_base styles_spacing-base styles_semibold">$105.99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="Item_description styles_small styles_base styles_spacing-base styles_line-default">Serves 6-8 People</div>
   </div>
</button>
```

Comment: never depend on what user do with input, just add validation to your controller and only receive what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preventing change values by users in inspect element and send it again to controller, you should use **CSRF_TOKEN** in input fields,

Take a look at here:

In laravel 5.6

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
   @csrf
...
</form>
```

And also Laravel has Validation for check all input type that you defined.

Here is the documerntation :

[Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)